# What is smell??How come 2 things have the same smell

Tags: everyday-chemistry, smell

I have been wondering **how something smells**.
How come something smells the same as other thing? What is similar in them?
Like what is the chemistry behind a particular smell of a substance?

---

For example compounds with SH (thiol) smell awful and similar, so what is similar between them? I know SH, but I am asking why can't they smell different.

Comment: You aren't surprised that two things may have the same _color_, are you?

Comment: I'm afraid unless you provide a certain example you question is way too broad.

Comment: This is probably more of a biology question, no? Smell is a property of the interaction between a molecule and the receptors in the nose. Although compounds with a similar smell may have the same functional groups, they may be very different. On the other hand, there is D/L- limonene that has a different smell for each of the two isomers.

Comment: The bit in your post that's suggestive of being off-topic(ish): "smell awful and similar". Smell is human perception, **not** a physical quantity, and hence doesn't really pertain to "pure" Chemistry. Sure, in Chemistry we talk about "smell" a lot, but that's really just limited to the laboratory ( "Phenolic" smell, "Pungent" smell, etc), but wanting to know **how** something has a particular odor is really more of a human physiology question. I'm not saying there's no Chem. involved...but this is way better off on the Biology.SE. As such, I vote to keep this closed.

Comment: Question could be migrated, but premise isn't true, I'm pretty sure one can make thiols with distinct smell. It's not that simple.

Comment: http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2006/04/20/sulfurous_stenches_a_connisseurs_guide

Comment: Smell is not one sense, or three like with colours, but a few hundred. Thiols strongly trigger one of them. And there *are* of course nuances in thiols. Stick your nose in there until the *thiol sense* is saturated, and you will start noticing. Wait, DON'T, thiols are not only disgusting but many of them also toxic.